# receiving deserialize position error randomly when using rangy library

Tags: javascript, dom, serialization, deserialization, rangy

I have been having some issues with rangy.

the error i recieve is:

Error: Error in Rangy Serializer module: deserializePosition() failed: node 
" has no child with index 3, 5"

I get this error when i pull serialized highlights from a database and try to deserialize them onto a web page. The really strange thing is most of the time the highlights are deserialized just fine and display on the page but at times they randomly disappear and I get the above mentioned error.

I used the chrome javascript debugger to track down the issue and

```
function deserializePosition(serialized, rootNode, doc) {
    if (!rootNode) {
        rootNode = (doc || document).documentElement;
    }
    var parts = serialized.split(":");
    var node = rootNode;
    var nodeIndices = parts[0] ? parts[0].split("/") : [], i = nodeIndices.length, nodeIndex;

    while (i--) {
        nodeIndex = parseInt(nodeIndices[i], 10);
        if (nodeIndex < node.childNodes.length) {
            node = node.childNodes[nodeIndex];
        } else {
            throw module.createError("deserializePosition() failed: node " + dom.inspectNode(node) +
                    " has no child with index " + nodeIndex + ", " + i);
        }
    }

    return new dom.DomPosition(node, parseInt(parts[1], 10));
}
```

in this code block for some reason at the line

```
var node = rootNode;
```

even though rootNode = html, the variable node gets assigned 'text' sometimes and this causes the node.childNodes.length to be equal to 0 and an error is thrown. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue randomly, did you find the root cause of this?